# name (amd properties) of a family of functions?

Tags: functions

I am looking for the generic name of such functions :

$f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+K.x}$

where $K$ is a constant

and in particular in the case of $K=1$ :
 $f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

in order to be able to gather their main known properties ...

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: thanks @john for your help on this,thanks a lot ! are these hyperbolas as well ? and if not, why not ?

Answer (score 2):

These are called Mobius functions.
$$F(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$. One interesting property is that when $a=-d$, they follow $F(F(X))=x$. This also happens when $b=c=0$ and $a=d$ and when $a=0=d$ but $bc \ne 0$

Comment: These are called Mobius transformations, to be precise. Mobius function is a [different thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobius_function).